# What's the difference between: application, program, process, job, task, service, daemon, script, command?

Tags: process, command, services, daemon, jobs

Can someone clearly provide the differences and/or equivalences between these terms? I always get something mixed up, and keep losing track whilst reading documentation...

---

Helpful previous answers:

- [What is the difference between a job and a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/what-is-the-difference-between-a-job-and-a-process)
- [Difference between process group and job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9082/difference-between-process-group-and-job)
- [What is the difference between Daemon and the normal running process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554765/what-is-the-difference-between-daemon-and-the-normal-running-process)
- [Difference between long running process and daemon?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74328/difference-between-long-running-process-and-daemon)

Ubuntu community:

- [What is the difference between jobs and services ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96026/what-is-the-difference-between-jobs-and-services)
- [Whats the difference between a job and a daemon ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030583/whats-the-difference-between-a-job-and-a-daemon)
- [What is technical difference between daemon service and process ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192058/what-is-technical-difference-between-daemon-service-and-process)
- [What are the differences between regular processes and services ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5036/what-are-the-differences-between-regular-processes-and-services)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** summary: none of these terms have a universal definition.

---

- *application*: the term is not universally well-defined, its definition depends on the context, the community, sometimes even the person using it.
- *program*: the term is not universally well-defined, its definition depends on the context, the community, sometimes even the person using it.
- *process*: the term is not universally well-defined, its definition depends on the context, the community, sometimes even the person using it.
- *job*: the term is not universally well-defined, its definition depends on the context, the community, sometimes even the person using it.
- *task*: the term is not universally well-defined, its definition depends on the context, the community, sometimes even the person using it.
- *service*: the term is not universally well-defined, its definition depends on the context, the community, sometimes even the person using it.
- *daemon*: the term is not universally well-defined, its definition depends on the context, the community, sometimes even the person using it.
- *script*: the term is not universally well-defined, its definition depends on the context, the community, sometimes even the person using it.
- *command*: the term is not universally well-defined, its definition depends on the context, the community, sometimes even the person using it.

(I think you are starting to see the pattern here.)

In all of these cases, you will have to ask the person using the term to define it. The only person that can tell you how a particular person uses that term is that particular person.

If you are reading an official standards document, the terms used in that standard will often be explicitly defined, in which case *only within this specific standards document*, the terms mean *exactly what the standards document says they mean*.

Let's just as an example look at only one of the terms, the term *command*, and let's further restrict ourselves only to the [Single Unix Specification version 4, 2018 Edition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/), Volumes [XBD (Base Definitions)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/idx/xbd.html) and [XCU (Shell & Utilities)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/idx/xcu.html).

In XBD Chapter 3 *Definitions*, [Clause 3.104 *Commands*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_104), the term *Command* is defined like this:

> ## 3.104 Command
>
> A directive to the shell to perform a particular task.
>
> ### Note:
>
> Shell Commands are defined in detail in XCU Shell Commands.

(By the way, notice how the definition itself uses the term *task*, which is also one of the terms you asked about, but which is not actually defined in the SUSv4.)

So, the SUSv4 seems to define the term *command* as "a directive to the shell to perform a particular task". And there is also a link to a more detailed definition in XCU Chapter 2 *Shell Command Language*, [Clause 2.9 *Shell Commands*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09):

> ## 2.9 Shell Commands
>
> […]
>
> A command is one of the following:
>
> - Simple command (see Simple Commands)
> - Pipeline (see Pipelines)
> - List compound-list (see Lists)
> - Compound command (see Compound Commands)
> - Function definition (see Function Definition Command)
>
> […]

And it goes on further to define each one of those in [2.9.1 *Simple Commands*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01), [2.9.2 *Pipelines*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02), [2.9.3 *Lists*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03), [2.9.4 *Compound commands*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04), and [2.9.5 *Function definition command*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05).

Great, so, does this mean that we now know what a *command* is? Well, not quite, because if we read the specification of the [`ed` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/ed.html) in [XCU Chapter 4 *Utilities*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/idx/utilities.html), we find that this uses the term *command* in a different way:

> ## DESCRIPTION
>
> The `ed` utility is a line-oriented text editor that uses two modes: *command mode* and *input mode*. In command mode the input characters shall be interpreted as commands, and in input mode they shall be interpreted as text. See the EXTENDED DESCRIPTION section.
>
> […]
>
> ## EXTENDED DESCRIPTION
>
> The `ed` utility shall operate on a copy of the file it is editing; changes made to the copy shall have no effect on the file until a **w** (write) command is given. The copy of the text is called the *buffer*.
>
> Commands to `ed` have a simple and regular structure: zero, one, or two *addresses* followed by a single-character *command*, possibly followed by parameters to that command. These addresses specify one or more lines in the buffer. Every command that requires addresses has default addresses, so that the addresses very often can be omitted. If the **-p** option is specified, the prompt string shall be written to standard output before each command is read.

And then it goes on to further define the structure of commands, and the various commands that exist.

So, even within the *same specification*, we already have found two different definitions of the term *command*. One is given explicitly as "A directive to the shell to perform a particular task." and the other is given implicitly as "A directive to the **`ed` utility** to perform a particular task."

But it gets even more interesting. If we look at the specification of the [`awk` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/awk.html), we find that, just like the shell, and just like the `ed` utility, we can supply "a directive to performa a particular task", so we might assume that this is also called a command. However, that is not the case:

> ## DESCRIPTION
>
> The `awk` utility shall execute programs written in the `awk` programming language, which is specialized for textual data manipulation. […]

So, the same concept that is called a *command* in `ed` is called a *program* in `awk`. Which is coincidentally another term that you asked about, but probably not the definition you thought it would have!

In the [`find` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/find.html), we again have a similar concept, but here it is neither called a *command* nor a *program*, but an *expression* made up of *primaries* and *operators*.

And in the [`pax` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/pax.html), we again have "a thing that tells the utility what to do", but here it is called the *mode*, which is however a completely different thing from what the [`chmod` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/chmod.html) calls a [*mode*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_227).

As you can see, even if we restrict ourselves to only a very narrow context (only the Single Unix Specification version 4, 2018 Edition, and in fact only two out of the four volumes) and only a single one of those terms, we can already find multiple different concepts described by that same term, as well as different terms to describe the same concept (or very similar, closely related concepts).